# Why does Grindenwald still posses the Elder Wand?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, gellert-grindelwald

At the end of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* Gellert Grindelwald is overpowered by Newt Scamander and taken to prison. Why does he still posses the Elder Wand?

Comment: I interpreted your question as _how_ Grindelwald can still _physically_ posses the Elder Wand at the start of TCoG. However, other users appear to have interpreted it as after FB who is the Elder Wand's _master_. Could you edit to clarify what it is you're asking here?

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought would be that the Elder Wand was held at MACUSA along with Grindelwald, however, it appears that Grindelwald had somehow hidden his wand from capture as apparently they only "found" it once he was to be transported.

> **SCENE 5**
>   **EXT. MACUSA ROOFTOP—MINUTES LATER—NIGHT**
>
> [...]
>
> **ABERNATHY:** Mr. Spielman, we found his wand hidden away.
>
> *He hands over a black rectangular box.*
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Official Screenplay*</sub>

It's worth noting though that this box contained the Chupacabra, Antonio, and not the Elder Wand. The Elder Wand itself was actually in possession of "Abernathy".

> **SCENE 5**
>   **EXT. MACUSA ROOFTOP—MINUTES LATER—NIGHT**
>
> [...]
>
> *The carriage plummets, then soars away through torrential rain. More AURORS follow on broomsticks.*
>
> *A beat.*
>
> *ABERNATHY steps forward, holding the Elder Wand. He looks up at the carriage, growing ever smaller. He Disapparates.*
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Official Screenplay*</sub>

However, it is later revealed that this "Abernathy" is actually Grindelwald and the "Grindelwald" that had been held prisoner during the transport was actually Abernathy. Therefore, it seems highly likely that Grindelwald had used his time as Abernathy to retrieve the Elder Wand before he was to be moved.

> **SCENE 7**
>   **INT. THESTRAL-DRAWN CARRIAGE—NIGHT**
>
> *SPIELMAN and GRINDELWALD sit, eyes locked, flanked by AURORS, all pointing their wands at GRINDELWALD. GRINDELWALD’S wand box lies on SPIELMAN’S lap.*
>
> *SPIELMAN holds up the vial, dangling from its chain.*
>
> **SPIELMAN:** No more silver tongue, eh?
>
> *But GRINDELWALD is transforming...*
>
> **SCENE 8**
>   **EXT. THESTRAL-DRAWN CARRIAGE—NIGHT**
>
> *ABERNATHY adjusts his grip underneath the carriage. His face too is changing. His hair is turning blond and lengthening... he is GRINDELWALD. He raises the Elder Wand.*
>
> **SCENE 9**
>   **INT. THESTRAL-DRAWN CARRIAGE—NIGHT**
>
> *GRINDELWALD’S rapid transformation into a tongueless ABERNATHY is almost complete.*
>
> **SPIELMAN:** *(shocked)* Oh!
>
> **SCENE 10**
>   **EXT. THESTRAL-DRAWN CARRIAGE—NIGHT**
>
> *Now fully transformed, GRINDELWALD Disapparates from the underside of the carriage...*
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Official Screenplay*</sub>

Comment: Did we ever see him use the Elder Wand in the first movie?  Seems to me that carrying it would have risked blowing his cover, so it would be unsurprising if it wasn't on him when he was caught.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Good point, been a while since I’ve seen it but I’d imagine he didn’t actually have it in his final battle in the film.